# Нужен совет по организации работы с git-ом!

Tags: git

Согласно рабочему регламенту работы с git-ом наши программисты создают свой брэнч и работают в нем. Потом код отправляется на код-ревью. После положительного результата кода-ревью, код вливается в основную ветку. Случился такой кейс, который озадачил меня и заставил обратиться сюда.

Как быть в случае, когда программист, работая в своей текущей ветке, находит в других модулях (не относящихся к реализации текущей фичи) незначительные ошибки или куски кода, требующие минимального рефакторинга?

Возможные варианты решения:

- Править их в ветке текущей фичи и вливать в основную ветку;
- Или создать новый специализированный брэнч под эти цели.

Comment: «код выливается в основную ветку» — понять это словосочетание, конечно, можно, но, приходится останавливаться.

Comment: думаю, отдельная ветка, отнаследованная от `master`. почему? если сделать reverse коммит, полезное потеряется. а также еще до мержа новой фичи (она может делаться год, например), соседи получат ценные доработки в других модулях. но вообще, это как вы договоритесь.

Comment: Не надо мешать все в кучу - если программист делает какую-то фичу, то в ветке должна быть __только__ эта фича. Никак не связанные с фичей доработки - складываете в бэклог и выполняете в других ветках. Мне, как ревьюеру, будет неясно почему вдруг вместе с фичей прилетают какие-то абсолютно несвязанные изменения.

Comment: Мне кажется, тут нет правильного ответа, это личное дело команды и тим-лида. Нам удобнее делать всё в той же ветке, если кому-то ещё нужны эти изменения, то он просто делает `cherry-pick` этого коммита. А насчёт разработки в отдельной ветке в течение года - само по себе это очень далеко от best practices...

Answer (score 0):

В момент обнаружения проблемы (баги, не оптимального кода, etc), не связанной с моей основной доработкой, я делаю так:

- Довожу свои изменения до компилируемого состояния
- Делаю коммит с комментарием "в процессе..."
- Вношу исправления
- Делаю отдельный коммит с максимально осмысленным комментарием
- Возвращаюсь к своим доработками
- Коммичу
- Создаю новую ветку
- Делаю в нее rebase коммитов по той проблеме
- Проверяю результат rebase'а
- rebase'ом убираю эти коммиты из своей ветки, заодно схлопываю коммиты "в процессе..." и проверяю/поправляю комментарии.
- Проверяю результат rebase'а
- Отправляю на ревью две отдельные ветки